# private int not retaining its value after being set

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` where an integer is declared in the constructor:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private int myInt;
}
```

I set the integer here:

```
private void setInt(int i) {
    myInt = i;
    Log.d("setting int", Integer.toString(myInt)); // logs proper value
}
```

`setDate()` is called on a listener:

```
private Dialog.OnSetListener l = new <>.OnSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSet(int arg1) { //arg1 is coming from the dialog
        setInt(arg1);
    }
}
```

Now, when the dialog is created with the integer, it retains the instantiated value (0) instead of the value set in `setInt`:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("onCreateDialog", Integer.toString(myInt); // Always 0
}
```

So to summarize, this is what the logs look like:

```
// first dialog creation (for @cybersam)
onCreateDialog: 0

// After picking 9 in the dialog
setting int: 9

// onCreateDialog:
onCreateDialog: 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

EDIT:

Complete exmaple:

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private int myInt;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("onCreateDialog", Integer.toString(myInt));

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, 2012, 12, myInt);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            // arg1 = year
            // arg2 = month
            // arg3 = day

            setDate(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        }
    };

    private void setDate (int y, int m, int d) {
        myInt = d;

        Log.d("setInt", Integer.toString(myInt));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. Verify that you're always operating on the same `MyDialogFragment` object.

Comment: Ok. Please see edits.

Comment: "private int not retaining its value after being set" - simply not possible :(  GUESS: you're inadvertantly doing the "set" on one object ... but them calling "onCreateDialog()" on a completely different object.  SUGGESTIONS:  1) Print the "this" object reference in your debug statements, 2) Try to reproduce the problem in an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using bundle args not trying to set variables - using args avoids a lot of issues with state (recreated fragments, etc).

```
private static final String INT_ARG = "int_arg";

public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int arg)
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(INT_ARG, arg);

    MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();

    if (args != null)
    {
        myInt = args.getInt(INT_ARG);
    }
}
```

When you want to show the dialog:

```
MyDialogFragment myFrag = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mInt);
myFrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is performing the "onCreateDialog" logging *before* it even creates the `DatePickerDialog`. So, your logging must actually be occurring in this order:

```
// onCreateDialog:
onCreateDialog: 0

// After picking 9 in the dialog
setting int: 9
```

Comment: Well, technically yes. But if i create the dialog again the integer that was set to a non zero value is logged as zero. I will make an edit to clarify.

Comment: `day` is a local variable.

Comment: Every time you launch `DatePickerDialogFragment`, you get a fresh local `myInt` variable, initialized to 0.

Comment: I thought the instance remained in memory and only `onCreateDialog` was called repeatedly?

Comment: What does [getRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getRetainInstance()) return? You can try calling [setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) to get that effect.

Comment: The docs do not say. Please dont speak in riddles, it helps no one.

Answer (score 0):

you need same instance variable for your program, you can use Singleton class or make an adjustment for your program use always same instance in this case.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do this?